# Accessing the variable inside anonymous namespace (c++)

Tags: c++, static, anonymous, unnamed-namespace

I have following code and I don't know how can I access the x inside the anonymous namespace in this setting. Please tell me how?

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 10;

namespace
{
    int x = 20;
}

int main(int x, char* y[])
{
    {
        int x = 30; // most recently defined
        std::cout << x << std::endl; // 30, local
        std::cout << ::x << std::endl; // 10, global
        // how can I access the x inside the anonymous namespace?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Don't do that.

Comment: Some related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622874/unnamed-namespace-access-rules

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you very much!

Comment: Why has the answer been given in the comments section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[You can't!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622896/560648)**

You cannot access the namespace's members by its name, because it doesn't have one.
It's anonymous.

You can only access those members by virtue of their having been pulled into scope already.

Comment: Thanks, then why does the people made such an inaccessible variable inside the namespace? What does it mean by accessing by virtue of their having been pulled into scope already? Could you please tell me more specific? :)

Comment: @DongkyuChoi: It means the object cannot be directly referenced outside that translation unit. It makes the object "file-local", in a sense. It's been pulled into that "file"'s scope, so you can use it there (as you show in your question), but nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to access it from a function within the anonymous same scope:

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 10;

namespace
{
    int x = 20;
    int X() { return x; }
}

int main(int x, char* y[])
{
    {
        int x = 30; // most recently defined
        std::cout << x << std::endl; // 30, local
        std::cout << ::x << std::endl; // 10, global
        std::cout << X() << std::endl; // 20, anonymous
        // how can I access the x inside the anonymous namespace?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no no no no! because X() is unique so if you add an outer function X() then this one will hide your inner X().

Comment: to be able to access data inside an anonymous namespace consider: Never declare any data outside  with the same name.

Comment: @Raindrop7 My answer isn't wrong.  This gives you 3 identifiers named 'x', in 3 different scopes, with 3 different ways of accessing them.  That's what OP asked for.  Whether its the right thing to do for the sake of code quality is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @TrevorHickey you have a unique X() which you depend on its return type which is the value of x. it matters when you have another X() outside. what will you do to get to the inner one??

Comment: You're talking hypotheticals.  There is no other X().  I agree that its a dangerous situation that could arise, but you don't know OP's intentions.  Maybe they are generating code.  Maybe they are going to use a unique enough function name.  Maybe they don't care.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You just exchanged `x` for `X()`. Okay so the OP doesn't have a global `int X()`. But this is really just shifting the goalpoasts. Now the question might as well be _"how do I write `::X()`?"_ Adding a layer of "indirection" doesn't change anything as far as access to that anonymous namespace goes.