# How to access the unnamed namespace with scope resolution?

Tags: c++, global, unnamed-namespace

I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Variable created inside namespace
namespace first
{
    int val = 500;
}

namespace
{
    int val = 400;
}

// Global variable
//int val = 100;

int main()
{
    // Local variable
    int val = 200;

    // These variables can be accessed from
    // outside the namespace using the scope
    // operator ::
    cout << first::val << '\n'; 
    cout << ::val << '\n'; 
    cout << val << '\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```

The `::val` in this case will provide `val = 400`. But if I remove the comment to the global variable then the global namespace will be reached by `::val`. So, in that case, how can I access the unnamed namespace?

`int val = 400;`

This is the output with

```
// Global variable
int val = 100; //Not commented.
```

```
500
100
200
```

Comment: Related: [Unnamed namespace access rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9622874/11082165)

Comment: You can't. Unnamed namespace has nothing that you can refer to in qualified name. Closest thing would be wrapping whole unnamed namespace in a named namespace (e.g. `detail`) or just naming your global variables more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to expand the unnamed namespace with a reference to the "hidden" variable:

```
#include <iostream>


// Variable created inside namespace
namespace first
{
    int val = 500;
}

namespace
{
    int val = 400;
}

// Global variable
int val = 100;

namespace {
    int& access_to_val=val;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // Local variable
    int val = 200;

    // These variables can be accessed from
    // outside the namespace using the scope
    // operator ::
    cout << first::val << '\n'; 
    cout << ::val << '\n'; 
    cout << val << '\n';
    cout << access_to_val << '\n'; 

    return 0;
}
```

Check the code with [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rEqn15WvP).

The output of the program is:

```
500
100
200
400
```

As a side remark: [avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) in the header.